# How to lookup same collection as foreign document in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

i have a collection called 'users' and inside that collection their is a field called friends which is an array.. it includes an user id.

```
{ 
  _id: 1
  username: xxx
  friends: [
     {
        userId: 2
     }
  ]
},
{
  _id: 2
  username: yyy
  friends: [
     {
        userId: 1
     }
  ]
}
```

i want to display user 2 data as friend of user 1
like this

```
friends: [
   {
     userId: 2
     username: yyy
   }
]
```

1st select user where _id = 1 then for all userId in friends output user data that matches userId and _id

Comment: in those question they are using 2 collections..i want to use lookup in one collection

Comment: Just replace the `from` expression with the current collection name it will work as expected.

Comment: mongoose Popuplate() function solved my problem